# How to change big json dynamicly in Karate framework?

Tags: json, dsl, karate

I have next JSON

```
{
  "updated": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "email": "api.test@test.io",
      "businessUnit": "US",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 21,
      "gender": "male"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "email": "api.test@test.io",
      "businessUnit": "US",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 22,
      "gender": "male"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "email": "api.test@test.io",
      "businessUnit": "US",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 23,
      "gender": "male"
    }
  ],
  "deleted": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "email": "api.test@test.io",
      "businessUnit": "US",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 31,
      "gender": "male"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "email": "api.test@test.io",
      "businessUnit": "US",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 32,
      "gender": "male"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "email": "api.test@test.io",
      "businessUnit": "US",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 33,
      "gender": "male"
    }
  ]
}
```

1. Is it possible to change 'id' fileds in other way rather than :

   - set req.updated[0].id = userId
   - set req.updated[1].id = userId
   - set req.updated[2].id = userId
2. Is it possible to change all 'id' fileds in both sections 'updated' and 'deleted' like :

   - set req[*].id = userId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: Okay so you want to use a bulk edit, and have some logic for incrementing id-s at the same time. So use transforms: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

Note that `karate.map(x, i)` takes an optional second argument that gives you the loop index.

```
* def data = [{}, {}, {}]
* def fun = function(x, i){ x.id = ~~(i + 1); return x }
* def payload = karate.map(data, fun)
* match payload == [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
```

Comment: Its not what I was asking for. I'll add more details than and hope it will help. Here is full test scenario, file leads.json is that was listed earlier :
https://gist.github.com/kasheylm/d0862c9c7110b1cd25f4eb13b5fdb163
I have two arrays with 3 elements each one, and I want to set uniq ID to each of 6 elements. I need a bulk set. I tried  transform functions but didnt succeed. I was wondering if you could do me a favour and show the right example for my scenario. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Denis - okay I edited my answer and I think it answers your question.

Comment: Many thanks, it works for me now and looks like this
`code`
* def userId = getId()
* def req = read('classpath:data/leads.json')
* def fun = function(x, i){ x.id = getId(); return x }
* def updated = karate.map(req.updated, fun)
* def deleted = karate.map(req.deleted, fun)
* print req
`code` 

Just one more thing - I have 2 karate.map operations for each of array. I tried to use something unified like
<code>
* def fun = function(x, i){ $x..id = getId(); return x }
* def res = karate.map(req, fun)
<code>
but it fails on $x..id. May be you know some more trick?))

Comment: @Denis open a new question please